# How can I modify a SQL query for take only some data from a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that works fine:

```
SELECT Parti.producttopgroup,
    Parti.productgroup,
    Parti.productsubgroup,
    Parti.manufacturer,
    Costruttore.longname AS Costruttore,
    Parti.supplier,
    Fornitore.longname AS Fornitore,
    Parti.partnr,
    Parti.ordernr,
    Parti.description1,
    Parti.description2,
    Parti.description3,
    Parti.packagingquantity,
    Parti.quantityunit
FROM tblPart AS Parti
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblAddress AS Costruttore 
        ON Parti.manufacturer = Costruttore.shortname
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblAddress AS Fornitore 
        ON Parti.supplier = Fornitore.shortname
```

I realized that the data contained in the database in some columns are multilingual, something like :

```
"it_IT@Ciao;en_US@Hello;..."
```

I need to have my data only in one language at time, so I have tried to adjust my query with the TRIM and REPLACE stateament, but no luck. There's a way for going from this string: "it_IT@Ciao;en_US@Hello;..." to  "Ciao"?

Comment: That design will cause you lots of problems...

Comment: I suppose you are right, but I can't cange the db, is not mine...

Comment: You can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: The design *is* the problem here, and it's the design that needs addressing.

Comment: Does it matter what one language you pick? Are there always the same amount of languages? Are they always sorted the same way?
This design just brings so much ambiguity...

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: sorry, but I've thinked it was clear...I've write my origial query. I don't know how I can modify it for having from this: "it_IT@Ciao;en_US@Hello;..." to this "Ciao". I need just the first language. I've tried the suggestion of Charlieface, but there is something wrong in the sintax

Comment: Well for a start you don't actually say in your question that you want this  "it_IT@Ciao;en_US@Hello;..." to this "Ciao" - so please do [edit] that into the question. And does this cover all edge cases? Is the logic from the first `@` to the following `;`? If so please add that to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should absolutely fix this design if you can, it's horrible.

Be that as it may, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` and `SUBSTRING` in a subquery

```sql
SELECT ...,
  YourColumn = (
    SELECT TOP (1) SUBSTRING(s.value, 7, LEN(s.value))
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.YourColumn, ';') s
    WHERE s.value LIKE 'en_US@%'
  )
FROM ...
```

If you just wanted the first one always then you can do

```sql
SELECT ...,
  YourColumn = SUBSTRING(LEFT(s.value, CHARINDEX(';', s.value) - 1), 7, LEN(s.value))
FROM ...
```

Comment: I know it's a terrible design, but the db it's not mine and the applicatione use it works with it fine. The number of languages is not alwais the same, but i neeed to take just the first.

Comment: The first language in the list? Or the first that matches a particluar language like `en_US`?

Comment: For now the first...so from char 7 to the first ";"

Comment: I've tried to modify the query as you suggest me, but there is something wrong...

Comment: 'SELECT  Parti.manufacturer, Costruttore.longname AS Costruttore, Parti.supplier, Fornitore.longname AS Fornitore, Parti.partnr, Parti.ordernr, Parti.packagingquantity,
 PArti.quantityunit=(SUBSTRING(LEFT(s.value, CHARINDEX(';', s.value) - 1), 7, LEN(s.value)))
FROM    tblPart AS Parti LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         tblAddress AS Costruttore ON Parti.manufacturer = Costruttore.shortname LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         tblAddress AS Fornitore ON Parti.supplier = Fornitore.shortname'

Comment: Works for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b322a2d04fdb34ce1b007fad8ec57eb although your syntax is off, should be `quantityunit =...` not `PArti.quantityunit =...`

Comment: I have find the problem...if the value is NULL i have a problem and the query can't execute